# Parse String to decimal and retain decimal values

Tags: javascript

I need to parse a string to (2) decimal points.

like so:

```
console.log("12345.6789"); // return 12345.67
```

The problem I am facing is that if the decimals are `.00` the numbers (decimals) are removed and a whole number is return instead.

```
console.log(parseFloat("123.00"))// return 123  // expected 123.00
console.log(parseFloat("123.01"))// return 123.01 // expected 123.01
```

If you are wondering why should this matter? It's because I need to present the data so it's very easy to scan for humans.

e.g: below is not pretty or easy to read (especially when text is align to the right) and we enter into the thousands and millions etc...

```
123.23
123,456.46
123
123,956.01
145
135.02
```

I need it to be like so:
    123.23
    123.46
    123.00
    123.01
    145.00
    135.02

Also the `typeof` should not be a string but an actual number.

```
123.00 // correct
"123.00"// incorrect // (I can use .tofixed() so this is not useful )
```

Comment: 123 == 123.00 in Javascript so no answer for this...

Comment: Right, I am not sure, if this was a data type issue, it was more of a scripting issue :) I think, `.toFixed()` is the appropriate thing to use so will stick with that :) many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

If value is text type:

```
 parseFloat("123.456").toFixed(2);
```

If value is number:

```
var numb = 123.23454;
numb = numb.toFixed(2);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This does not the work the way you try it. You **want** a string. Indisputably, `3.00` is the same as `3` if you save it as a number and printing will make no difference. You want to manually add the "0"s and therefore you have to create a string. 
**.tofixed()** is perfectly fine for this use. If you print stuff, it is converted to a string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you print to the console

```
console.log( (123).toFixed( 2 ) ); // outputs "123.00"
```

However, the quotes around the output are just to illustrate the fact that it is a string. It should be fine to use `.toFixed()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have already said, the `toFixed()` function will take care of the fractional part.
If you also want to add thousand separator for readability, you can use a simple regex as described **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)**.

```
var d = ...   // <-- this is a number
var str = d.toFixed(2)
           .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
           //  ^-- use this "replace()" to add thousand separators
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/y4n7p/)**.